# How to avoid comparison without maintaining session?

Tags: c#

I have one web page, which displays the data which has been captured earlier. Now this data comes from database and belongs to multiples records of a database table.When user updates this data, we have to update our database records.Problem is I can not keep track of which records has been modified and since we don't have session. So I have fetch all the records again and compare with data from web page. If any one knows better ways of doing it(avoiding the comparison) please help me out.

Comment: I think this is not a good practice you should use some kind of data binding mechanism here. Normally developers shouldn't worry about these kind of things. Please dig in on Data Binding topics and you will get a better idea on how to handle this kind of situations.

Answer (score 1):

Use a primary key of your record to identify it. 
When you render the form for editing records you can output primary key in a hidden field.

If you have a page that allows updating multiple records at the same time than you could skip the comparison and always update all the records - if you use MSSQL 2008 or newer you can use table-valued parameter to pass *all* the records to DB in one call and use MERGE command to do bulk update.

You could also write javascript that will trigger on each input edit and sets a 'dirty' flag for the modified record (hidden field). You will than know wich rows were edited.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Jakub. But what if user has deleted something (some record).How to detect that one?

Comment: You can use the 'dirty' flag with value `deleted` instead of `edited`. For new records set the flag to `new`.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more how it is avoiding comparison if we don't want to do bulk update.

Comment: You just look at the flag to identify which records were modified and therefore you don't have to load all records from DB and compare them to the values user submitted.

Comment: how can we make that which data has been modified.A user can modify data to different value and again modify to original value.

Comment: In that case you need to store the original value in another hidden field or data-* attribute.